# Is there a R function in R Shiny to know the means across categories

Tags: r, shiny

I need to make the below code interactive. I need to know the means of the categories in the table. Once I execute the code, I get following error:

> $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

I see some error in the code

```
output$mean <- renderUI({tapply(Unit_Price, Material, mean)})
```

---

```
Unit_Price <- c(60, 49, 40, 61, 64, 60, 59, 54, 62, 69, 70, 42, 56,
                61, 61, 61, 58, 51, 48, 65, 49, 49, 41, 48, 52, 46,
                59, 46, 58, 43)

Material <- c("tas", "sa", "qld", "nsw", "nsw", "nt", "wa", "wa",
              "qld", "vic", "nsw", "vic", "qld", "qld", "sa", "tas",
              "sa", "nt", "wa", "vic", "qld", "nsw", "nsw", "wa",
              "sa", "act", "nsw", "vic", "vic", "act")

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(selectInput("x","Value of x",choices = c("ComA","ComB")),
                 checkboxInput("mean","Mean Prices are"),
                 uiOutput("mean")),
    mainPanel(h6("Here it is"),
              tableOutput("message")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$message <- renderTable(
    {
      if(input$x == "ComA")
      {
        data.frame(Unit_Price,Material)
      } else 
      {
        if(input$x == "ComB")
        {
          data.frame(Material=c("A","B"),Unit_Price=c(7,8))
        }
      }
    }
  )
  output$mean <- renderUI({tapply(Unit_Price, Material, mean)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What's happening in your `renderUI`? That should contain shiny functions that generate UI elements (such as `tableOutput` or `selectInput`), instead you're just passing a data frame to nothing. How and where do you want that data to appear?

Answer (score 0):

If you exchange the the `renderUI` with `renderTable` at least you don't get an error message anymore.

Thats the server part:

```
  output$mean <- renderTable(rownames = TRUE, {
    a <- tapply(Unit_Price, Material, mean)
    data.frame(a)
  })
```

The UI part also has to be adapted accordingly. So `uiOutput` becomes `tableOutput`.

But it's still not very clear to me what you are actually trying to achieve.
Should the data `Unit_Price` and `Material` be interactive, so that you calculate the means of the currently selected data.frame?
If so then it would make sense to create that data.frame in a `reactive`, that you can access in all other server functions.

Right now you just switch between them and show them in a table, but the means are always calculated for the values you assigned outside of the server function.

Here's an example using a reactive for the data.

*EDIT:* Since the means table should only appear when the checkbox is clicked, I included a small `req(input$mean)` in `output$mean`, which waits until the checkbox is clicked and returns TRUE, otherwise the code wont run, and the table wont show up.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(selectInput("x","Value of x",choices = c("ComA","ComB")),
                 checkboxInput("mean","Mean Prices are"),
                 tableOutput("mean")),
    mainPanel(h6("Here it is"),
              tableOutput("message")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data <- reactive({
    if (input$x == "ComA") {
      data.frame(Unit_Price, Material)
    } else if (input$x == "ComB") {
      data.frame(Material=c("A","B"), Unit_Price=c(7,8))
    }
  })

  output$message <- renderTable({
    data()
  })

  output$mean <- renderTable(rownames = TRUE, {
    req(input$mean)
    df <- data()
    tapply(df$Unit_Price, df$Material, mean)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yes this is what i wanted, But actually when I click the checkbox " Mean Prices are" the output should come and not before that. Why checkbox is not working

Comment: Because we are not listening for it. I'll edit my answer to include that

Comment: Perfect. But I did not understand why reactive is put in place of renderTable?

Comment: The reactive is used to create the dataframe that you can use anywhere in the server function. And since you use 2 `renderTables` which access the same dataframe, it makes sense to use a reactive dataframe. If you would just use the data once, then you could do everything in the renderTable part.

Comment: Perfect. When taking this code forward, I need to add a function              
stderr <- function(x) sqrt(var(x)/length(x)) then i can apply tapply(df$Unit_Price, df$Material, stderr). Can I add this fucntion in UI?

Comment: Of course you can. Just follow the logic of the mean-table.